# How to setup a model for a guillotine cutting stock problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

**Backgroud.** 
I'm reading papers about cutting stock problem (CSP).

1. Said Ben Messaoud, Chengbin Chu, Marie-Laure Espinouse (2008)
   [Characterization and modelling of guillotine constraints](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221707009083).
   European Journal of Operational Research 191 (2008) 112–126.
2. D.A. Wuttke, H.S. Heese (2017) [Two-dimensional cutting stock
   problem    with sequence dependent setup times](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2017.07.036), European Journal
   of    Operational Research

**Problem**

There is a square canvas, the side of the canvas is $n\times a$.

It is required to cut this canvas into $n^2$ equivalent squares with the side, $a$.

For $n = 3$, we can easily get the solution: $9$ squares with the side $a_1=a_2=...=a_9=a$, where $a_i$ the side of $i$-th square, $i \in I = \{1,2,\ldots, n^2\}$. If we remove any square, we will have a classic [$8$-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) (left figure below, $n=3$).

[image]

At first, let us now omit the constraint on squares' side size, they can be different: $$a_1 <a_2 <... <a_i <... <a_{n ^ 2}. \tag{1}$$

At second, let us add the following constraints on squares' sides (right figure above, $n=3$):

1. The sum of any two consecutive elements of the set $(1)$ must be greater  the following element.
2. Any element of the set $(1)$ must be less than half of the canvas, $n\times a$.
3. The first element of the set $(1)$ must be greater than the half of equivalent solution, $a$.

**The task is to prove:**

a) the problem will have a solution (integer or real),

b) the solution is $(n^2-1)$-puzzle.

**Question.** How to setup a model for an optimization problem?

**My attempt is:**

I think I have a case of [guillotine cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillotine_problem).

I have tried to write the constrains (C1)-(C3):

$$ s.t. \left\{%
\begin{array}{ll}
a_ {i + 2} < a_i + a_ {i + 1} ,& i = 1,2, ..., n ^ 2-2; \\
a_i <\frac{n\times a}{2}, & \forall i \in I;  \\
0 < a/2 < a_1. \\
\end{array}%
\right.$$

**Update.**

Here is [the list of software](http://www.culand.ch/dev/SBPSolver.htm) (see at bottom of page) to design, test, and solve your own original sliding block puzzles.